# Differences in sklearn's RidgeCV options

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm a bit confused about what appear to be bigger-than-expected differences under certain arguments for RidgeCV. The variations that are confusing to me are below:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale 

boston = scale(load_boston().data)
target = load_boston().target

alphas = np.linspace(0,200)
fit0 = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, store_cv_values=True, 
gcv_mode='eigen').fit(boston, target)
fit0.alpha_
#4.0816326530612246

alphas = np.linspace(0,200)
fit1 = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, store_cv_values=True, gcv_mode='svd').fit(boston, target)
fit1.alpha_
#0.0

fit2 = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, cv=10).fit(boston, target)
fit2.alpha_
#114.28571428571429

fit3 = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, cv=len(target)).fit(boston, target)
fit3.alpha_
#0.0
```

In the first case, fit0, using gcv_mode='eigen', the alpha parameter selected always seems to be the first non-zero alpha in alphas.

In fit1, alpha=0 is always selected, this is somewhat strange, since the cv_value associated with 0 is nan. The other values appear the same as under the 'eigen' case, which is expected.

In fit2, I get what I believe is the most reasonable answer of the bunch, a value somewhere in the middle of the range. Obviously this is partly determined by the random assignment to folds.

In fit 3, which I understand should be the computationally more intensive equivalent to 0 and 1 I do at least match the result of fit1, but I'm not convinced as to why.

My current theories in order of plausability are:

1. Something's not right in my understanding of what these options do.
2. Something not quite kosher is going on with selected the best parameter when nan is involved as in case fit1 (though I don't see why this would affect fit3)
3. This is a particularly idiosyncratic data set, I understand it's probably not a great candidate for regularization given relatively small number of features.
4. Something else.

Can anyone help me understand what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things are happening here, I believe.

There is correlation structure in the data, and cv=10 doesn't shuffle. If you shuffle the data before using `boston, target = shuffle(boston, target, random_state=3)` It seems very dependent on the random state, though.

I don't know why the eigen mode is so much different, probably due to dataset issues, but I'm not sure.

Where do you say the NaN pops up, I don't see it when reproducing.
Anyhow, I agree that something odd is happening here. Feel free to open an issue on the issue tracker.